# How to define a float matrix in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I am trying to define a float matrix using this code in python 2.7:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1/16,1/8,1/16],[1/8,1/4,1/8]])
print A
```

The result matrix is a floor value matrix (int value matrix):

```
[[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]
```

How can I fix it to a float martix?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `1/16` is an *integer* expression. You divide the integer `1` with the integer `16`, resulting in the integer `0`.

Use floating-point values instead, like `1.0 / 16.0`.

Answer (score 0):

As Some programmer dude pointed out, the error lies in your definition of the matrix: Python < 3 performs integer division, so numpy correctly assumes the data type is int and creates an int array.

Besides fixing that by replacing `1/16` with `1./16.`, you can always force numpy to use a certain data type:

```
A = np.array([0, 1, True], dtype=float)
```